# Send thank you email in wordpress after user is redirected from other website

Tags: wordpress

This is the problem I am trying to find a solution to: I manage a wordpress site that deals with donations. There are 5 options. Once the user clicks on one of them they are sent to a third party site to make a donation. After they make the donation they are redirected back to my site with a set of data (name, email etc.). What I need to do is get that data and send a thank you email to the user. Is there some wordpress plugin I can use to handle the incoming data and send the email? Or maybe use a plugin like Contact form 7 to do it? I am not really familliar with wordpress. Really basic knowledge

Comment: For payment which gateway you are using ?

Comment: Payment is being handled by the 3rd party. We have nothing to do with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to create a custom page template with logic to capture the data sent after donating in it and apply the template to a page.

E.g.

**wp-content/themes/your-theme/ipn.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: IPN
 */

// Grab the data that's returned, however it's returned.
$data = $_GET['data'];

// Use WordPress mail function to send your email
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );

// Either redirect to another page or display a thank you message.
```

Then go into your admin, create a new page called IPN, select your page template from the drop down and publish. You can use the URL to this page to pass data back to it from the 3rd party site after payment.

Comment: Worked great. Thank you

Comment: @GeorgeDedoulis no problems mate, happy to help.